# TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not MyClass

Tags: python, pygame

I want to animate a Sprite `Worker` move horizontally from left side to the right. Also, I have another Sprite which is a static background image.

The code fails at line `screen.blit(worker, (w_x,w_y))` with the error message:

> TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not Worker

I understand that it's possible to only blit surfaces, not `Worker`. But how can I put `Worker` into surface in order to animate it?

I am very new to PyGame. Therefore any help will be highly appreciated.

Code:

```
import pygame, random

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (20, 255, 140)
GREY = (210, 210 ,210)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
PURPLE = (255, 0, 255)

SCREENWIDTH=1000
SCREENHEIGHT=578

class Worker(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image_file, location):
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        # super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image_file)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.left, self.rect.top = location


class Background(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image_file, location):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image_file)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.left, self.rect.top = location

pygame.init()

size = (SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("TEST")

#all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

worker = Worker("worker.png", [0,0])
w_x = worker.rect.left
w_y = worker.rect.top

bg = Background('bg.jpg', [0,0])

carryOn = True

while carryOn:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                carryOn=False

        screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(bg.image, (SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT)), bg.rect)

        #Draw geo-fences
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREEN, [510,150,75,52])
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREEN, [450,250,68,40])

        w_x += 5
        screen.blit(worker, (w_x,w_y))

        #Refresh Screen
        pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pygame.Surface.blit`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) takes another `pygame.Surface` as the first argument, but you're passing a `Worker` object. Just pass the `image` attribute of the worker:

```
screen.blit(worker.image, (w_x,w_y))
```

---

You could also put your sprite objects into a [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) and blit all of the sprites with the `draw` method.

Outside of the while loop:

```
sprite_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
# Add the sprites.
sprite_group.add(worker)
```

Inside the while loop:

```
sprite_group.update()  # Call the `update` methods of all sprites.

sprite_group.draw(screen)  # Blit the sprite images at the `rect.topleft` coords.
```

Comment: Thanks. If I use `sprite_group`, there is no need to do `screen.blit(...)` inside while loop?

Comment: Yes, you just need to call `update` and `draw` once per frame to update and blit all sprites in the group.

Comment: But how do I pass new positions if I animate a Sprite? For example, I can do `screen.blit(worker.image, (w_x,w_y))` when using `blit`. I do not understand how to pass `w_x` and `w_y`, if I only use `sprite_group.update()` and `sprite_group.draw(screen)` without `blit`.

Comment: You can do that by updating the `self.rect.x` or `.y` positions in the `update` method of the sprite, e.g. `self.rect.x += 5`.